# Running multi-module Play tests from SBT

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt, ebean

I'm quite stuck at the moment with my multi-module Play project.

I have 2 Play projects and 3 libraries. As the projects are interdependent (APIs are strongly linked) I'd like to manage all the projects through a single Build.scala file. In this way I could be able to compile everything and run all tests from a single line (sbt test). However I'm really confused about ebeans during the test phase.

I'm able to launch all tests but I get a PersistenceException due to classes being mixed whereas my model is not enhanced. I've checked the application.conf and added "ebeanEnabled := true" but it still doesn't work.

Here's my project layout:

`main/
  |___ project/
             |_____ Build.scala
             |_____ plugins.sbt (in which I've declared the play plugin)
  |___ playProject1/
             |_____ app/
             |_____ conf/
                         |_____ application.conf
  |___ playProject2/
             |_____ app/
             |_____ conf/
                         |_____ application.conf`

I'm running "sbt test" from the root directory.

Here's my Build.scala example file : https://gist.github.com/sdjamaa/352eace1d19333f9c50d

What am I missing?

Comment: I have a similar setup, but only have one applicaiton.conf in main project. According play docs that's how it should be setup.